# ESP32 with PulsesensorPlayground

Tags: iot, esp32

I am new in developing Arduino and I encounter bugs already. I have searched in the internet but still no luck.

The situation is, I have an ESP32 Dev Kit with 32 pins and I have this PulseSensor from pulsesensor.com. I tried the example Getting_BPM_to_Monitor in the PulseSensorPlayground Library and encountered problems.

The problem is in the void setup function pulsesensor can not create a object here.

My code:

```
const int PulseWire = 0;     
const int LED13 = 13;       
int Threshold = 550;

PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;

void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);
    pulseSensor.analogInput(PulseWire);
    pulseSensor.blinkOnPulse(LED13);
    pulseSensor.setThreshold(Threshold);
    if (pulseSensor.begin()){
        Serial.println("We created a pulseSensor Object !");
    } else 
        Serial.println("Cannot create a pulseSensor Object !"); //this code is added to check if it creates the object
}
```

Comment: `begin()` does not "create an object" the `PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;` line did that.  What if anything begin does is something you will have to check the library source or documentation for.  Is the library known to be ESP32 compatible?

Comment: I checked that library and it says that it already supports esp32.

Pulse sensor Library [link](https://github.com/WorldFamousElectronics/PulseSensorPlayground)

Comment: The issues at your link suggest that perhaps it really doesn't work on the ESP32 at least without option changes

Comment: Thank you but how could I make the option changes ? 

Thank you in advance for helping me.

Comment: The best source of that information would be the link you posted earlier yourself.

Comment: Hello sir Chris,

can you help me, I added in my code the 

`#define ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32 true`

because in the library it has a code specifically for ESP32 

    `#if defined(ARDUINO_ARCH_ESP32)`
    `// can't use analogWrite yet...`
    `#define NO_ANALOG_WRITE = 1`
    `#endif`

Comment: Again, your need to take time to study the ESP-related issues at the project repository link which you posted yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never use PulseSensor so I don't know whether it supports ESP32 or not. But I think your code is directly copy form Arduino and try to run it on ESP32.

How exactly you connect the PulseSensor to ESP32? i.e. Which pin the pulse sensor is connected to ESP32?

In Arduino, `const int PulseWire = 0;` which you used for analogRead make sense as it is referring to A0, but for ESP32 Arduino Core, ADC0 is at GPIO36 (see [ESP32 Arduino Core pinmap](https://github.com/espressif/arduino-esp32#esp32dev-board-pinmap), it will simply not work.

In order to connect the analog sensor to ESP32 ADC0, you will need to define the PulseWire as 36.

```
const int PulseWire = 36;
```